# Is there any way to "squeeze" all of a video's frames to a constant frame rate using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that is very jumpy. It freezes after every couple of seconds, and running the MediaInfo reveals a frame rate of 23.701fps. The original video has 23.976fps and is shorter than the faulty version by a couple of seconds. This plays fine on VLC. They both have the same size so it looks like the faulty one has some frames stretched over to fit the additional seconds. Is there an ffmpeg command I can use to repair this video?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make the faulty video from the original video?

Comment: No. I got both these videos from the internet